# help with linked list template

Tags: c++, g++, linked-list

I need some help with my linked list.  I think the problem is in the copy constructor or the assignment overload. it keeps giving my segmentation fault when i call: 
(Queue test_int_copy(test_int);)
Any other error or poor implementation that you can see would also be very helpful.
the .h file

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

template <class Object>
class Queue
{
 public:
     Queue();
     //initializes empty queue

     Queue(const Queue& a_queue);
     //copy constructor

     Queue& operator =(const Queue& rhs);
     //overload assignment operator

     bool enqueue(const Object& d);
     //insert object into queue,return true
     //return false if not

     bool dequeue(Object& d);
     //remove object from queue,return true
     //if empty return false

     bool isEmpty();
     //check if empty

     ~Queue();
     //destructor

private:
    struct ListNode
    {
        Object obj;
        //object that is in the list

        ListNode *next;
        //pointer to the next node

    };
    //struct of list

    ListNode *head;
    //pointer that points to head
};

#endif //Queue_H
#include "queue.cpp"  //include queue.cpp with file
```

the .cpp file

```
     #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class Object>
Queue<Object>::Queue()
{
    head = NULL;
}

template <class Object>
Queue<Object>::Queue(const Queue<Object> &a_queue)
{
    head = NULL;
  ListNode *nodePtr = a_queue.head;
    while (nodePtr){
      enqueue(nodePtr->obj);
      nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }

}

template <class Object>
Queue<Object>& Queue<Object>::operator =(const Queue<Object> &rhs)
{
    //head = NULL;
  ListNode *nodePtr = rhs.head;
  Object temp;
    while(head){
      dequeue(temp);
    }
    while (nodePtr){
      enqueue(nodePtr->obj);
      nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }
}

template <class Object>
bool Queue<Object>::enqueue (const Object& d) //Enqueue
{
    ListNode *newNode = new ListNode;
    newNode->obj = d;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    ListNode *nodePtr = NULL;
    ListNode *previousNode = NULL;

    if(isEmpty()){
        head = newNode;
        return true;
        }
    else{
        nodePtr = head;
        while(nodePtr != NULL){
            previousNode = nodePtr;
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }
        if(previousNode->next == NULL){
            previousNode->next = newNode;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}

template <class Object>
bool Queue<Object>::dequeue (Object& d)  //Dequeue
{
    ListNode *nodePtr;

    if(!head)
        return false;
    else{
      if(head->next != NULL){
            nodePtr = head;
            d = nodePtr->obj;
            head = head->next;
            delete nodePtr;
            return true;
      }
      else{
        d = head->obj;
        head = NULL;
        return true;
      }
    }
}


template <class Object>
bool Queue<Object>::isEmpty() //Check if Empty
{
    if(!head)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

template <class Object>
Queue<Object>::~Queue()   //Destructor
{
    Object temp;
    while(head)
        dequeue (temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize your head pointer in your copy constructor (and also in your operator = function by the way). If you don't do so, head might end up with an undefined value and fail the IsEmpty test, witch may lead to a crash in enqeue.

Answer (score 2):

Also don't include the source file like that. Or if you insist, make sure to put it inside the include guard. e.g.

```
#include "queue.cpp"  //include queue.cpp with file
#endif //Queue_H
```

Otherwise if the header is included multiple times (which happens all the time), you'll have a compilation error. (STuff will be defined multipled times).

Also, if you're going to include the "source" from the header -- make sure all functions are "inline" (implicitly or explicitly), otherwise you'll get linker errors

Answer (score 1):

One mistake I can see: in the dequeue() method, you do not set head to NULL after removing the last item.

Also, in the assignment overload:

```
while(head){
      dequeue(temp);
      head = head->next;
    }
```

... You do not need to set head = head->next, that has already been done by the dequeue() method.

Comment: does doesnt "delete head" make the head NULL??

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `enqueue()` function always inserts a node in the end. So it's better to maintain an extra member variable as: `ListNode *tail;`pointing to the last node of the list. So when you are adding a node you don't need to traverse through whole list and simply update the `*tail`. This will save lot of time.
2. For whatsoever reason you return `false` from `enqueu()`, do NOT forget to `delete newNode;` otherwise it will leak memory.
3. `isEmpty()` you can simplify as `bool isEmpty() { return (0 != head); }`.
4. Instead of declaring & passing a raw object in `dequeue()`, you can simply return `Object*` if element is removed or return `0 (NULL)` if it's empty; that's equivalent to `true` and `false`.
5. Importantly, whenever you `delete head;` always do `head = 0;`. Because that's a member variable and should not be dangling.